# SharePoint Calendar change

Tags: sharepoint, localization

I want to know if it's possible to change sharepoint calendar to work with different cultures. I want month names and day names changed, years set to a different number(like 4009, or 1009) without changing the server time, and number of days in every month changed(like first six month all 31 days, and the next 5 months all 30 days and one month 29 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendar will follow the regional settings on your site. So you can change this by go in to Site Actions->Site settings->Site Administration->Regional settings.

Regarding the second question. I suppose that if you have the need to change the world order of dates, you need to develop your custom web part.